# How to display real count of selected item from ion-list?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I am build a new suppression page for mobile app. For legacy reasons we are using, ionic 3 angular 5.

Problem I am facing is getting a real count of ion-items selected from a list of ion-select mulitple=true items. I have following html

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Select Nodes</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedNodes" multiple="true">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let node of incident.context['nodes']" value={{node}}>{{ node }}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

`incident.context['nodes']` contains a list like `["foo", "bar","baz"]` Once selection is made it is displaying the list of selected items. But I want to display the count instead. How do I do that?

Comment: did you  try `selectedNodes.length`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to do it. You could however modify the DOM directly (eg. using Angular [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)) to show the length. Try the following

1. Bind an event handler (`onChange()` here) to `ngModelChange` event.

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label #select>Select Nodes</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ngModelChange)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="selectedNodes" multiple="true">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let node of incident.context['nodes']" value={{node}}>{{ node }}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

2. The selected items are displayed in a container in DOM with class `.select-text`. Modify it's `innerHTML` property directly in the event handler.

```js
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

...
export class AppComponent {
  selectedNodes = [];
  incident = {
    context: {
      nodes: ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4' ]
    }
  };

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  onChange() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.select-text');
      this.renderer.setProperty(element, 'innerHTML', this.selectedNodes.length);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3-list-data-9cswst)

---

<sup>Without the `setTimeout` the `innerHTML` property would not be changed as it may be perceived as not yet available. It's a quick workaround.</sup>

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if selectedNode is the array that is containing the list of items you selected, you can simply display length of the array to show total selected items.

```
    <ion-list> 
    <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Total Count</ion-label> 
    {{selectedNodes.length}}
    </ion-select> 
    </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```